# jquery unbind and off does not work on image

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to only execute the slide fade in of the image once when it detects that its being shown on the page. Things that I've tried:

```
$(this).unbind();
$(this).unbind("scroll");
$(this).off();
$(this).off("scroll");
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jsyx0p9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong part was you use `$(this)` instead of using `$(window)`, in your fiddle `$(this)` will refer to `.fade-in` div..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.fade-in').each(function(i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object - $(this).outerHeight() / 2) {
                $(this).animate({
                    opacity : 1,
                    marginLeft : '+=200px'
                }, 500);
            }
            $(window).off("scroll");
        });
    });
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jsyx0p9/2/)..

**EDITED** Fiddle for multi-divs: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5jsyx0p9/3/)

Comment: What if i wanted multiple fade-in elements? This would disable the fade in function after the first one

Comment: You should change the class of current animated `.fade-in` div to another class. By doing that, you don't need `$(window).off("scroll");` anymore.